# GridView on update check if a value from a cell is equal to something then insert values into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

- I have a gridview and on row update I want to check if the value from
  a cell is equal to something

The code was compiled I made a test to check if it works and it's not adding the values to the database , but if I delete the condition of checking if it's equal to smth . it works , it's adding the values from a ROW into the database.

```
      GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string conn = "connection string";
            string str = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;

                string sqlquerry = "INSERT INTO table (Column1,Column2";
                sqlquerry += " VALUES (@V,@V2)";
if(str == "Hi"){
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(string))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquerry, conn))
                    {
                        cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("V", e.OldValues[0].ToString());
                        cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("V2", e.NewValues[1].ToString());
                        Conectare.Open();
                        cmmd.ExecuteReader();

                }
            }
```

}

Comment: Why do you use ExecuteReader? It should be ExecuteNonQuery.

Comment: equals method? I don't know it

Comment: I mean to say try str.equals("Hi")  and also it should be executeNonQuery rather that ExecuteReader actually i didnt care about that coz you said without if(condition) it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it is a insert query you should use 
'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery' and then compare the string with equals method.